# Javascript : long string to smaller pieces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do a bookmarklet which obtains some information from a certain website.

After using `$('#div').text();` and avoiding the html elements that are inside the div, i get the following string:

> ```
>                   TOP-GOST d.o.o.
>
>                   Tel:
>
>               01 200 50 80 , 041 843 303
>
>                   E-mail: 
>                       info@via-bona.com
>
>                 Spletna stran podjetja
>
>
>                   Tbilisijska ulica 59
>                   1000 Ljubljana 
>                   Slovenija
> ```

As you can see there is alot of unnecessary spaces and different information inside one big string. What i would like to do is to remove all spaces, remove unnecessary information (as Tel:, E-mail:, Spletna stran podjetja) and separate important information with comma `','`.

Is it possible to put every independent part of information into its own variable? My solution would be something similar to `php's explode()` or inverted javascript `join()`, after pieces are glued together with a comma.

About removing the unnecessary parts, is using a  `.replace().` good idea?

**Desired result:**

```
variable one_string = 'TOP-GOST d.o.o., 012005080, 041843303, info@via-bona.com, Tbilisijska u...';

AND LATER

variable title = 'TOP-GOST d.o.o.'
variable phone = '012005080,041843303'
variable email = 'info@via-bona.com'

etc.
```

**Original source code HTML:**

```
<div class="offer-contact">
<h3 class="offer-company">
    TOP-GOST d.o.o.</h3>
<strong>
    Tel:
</strong>
01 200 50 80 , 041 843 303<br>
<strong>
    E-mail:</strong> <a href="mailto:info@via-bona.com">
        info@via-bona.com</a><br>
<strong>
<a href="http://www.via-bona.com" target="_blank">Spletna stran podjetja</a><br>

</strong></div><strong>                               

<div class="offer-map">
<p>
    Tbilisijska ulica 59<br>
    1000 Ljubljana <br>
    Slovenija<br>

</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, what's the pattern for "important information"? Or what's the pattern for "trivial information"?

Comment: Is the structure constant? Then you can use simple regex to get the email and phone numbers. Ill quickly write a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: Learn about the tools you use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: I updated with original source code html.

Comment: @elclanrs Important information is 'TOP-GOST d.o.o., 012005080, 041843303, info@via-bona.com, Tbilisijska ulica 59,1000 Ljubljana, Slovenija, /url/'. And yes structure is constant.

Comment: The opposite of `join()` is `split()` in most sane programming languages. (So, not PHP.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `$('#div').text();` and avoiding the html elements that are inside the div

Why aren't you using the HTML structure instead of discarding it? Instead of accessing `$('#div')`, why not access `$('#phone')`, `$('#email')`... separately? If they don't have ID, but have stable structure, you can use `$('#div > div:nth-child(3)')` kind of selectors to pinpoint what you're looking for.

**EDIT**: Now that we can see the structure:

```
var title = $('.offer-company').text().trim();
var email = $('.offer-contact a').attr('href').trim();
var address_array = $.map($('.offer-map p').html().split('<br>'), function(v) {
  var t = v.trim();
  if (t.length) return t;
});
// Phone is trickier; it's not in a tag by itself. So, this
// is the more reliable method (get rid of everything else):
var $offer = $('.offer_contact').clone();
$offer.find('.offer-company, strong, br, a').remove()
var phone_array = $.map($offer.html().split(','), function(v) {
  var t = v.trim();
  if (t.length) return t;
});
// The alternative would have been to go with regexp, which
// is not recommended for cutting up HTML.
```

Something like this should do it. If you need the comma-separated string of address or phones, you can do `address_array.join(', ')` (same for phones).

Comment: This arguably should've been a comment asking for clarification, although now that the source HTML is there it could be made into an actual solution.

Comment: @millimoose: And now it is. :p

Answer (score 2):

try getting rid of consecutive whitespace like this:

```
$('#div').text().replace('\n', ' ').replace(/\s\s*/g, ' ');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Yy24/)